Does Pact of the Chain allow casting Find Familiar in a single Magic action?
Does the Pact of the Chain invocation allow a Warlock to cast Find Familiar in a single Magic action, despite its usual one-hour casting time? While the invocation’s description and the rules on the Magic action seem straightforward, the wording opens room for interpretation.
The Pact of the Chain invocation states:

You learn the Find Familiar spell and can cast it as a Magic action without expending a spell slot.

At first glance, this could be taken to mean Find Familiar becomes a free spell cast (no spell slot required) but with its standard one-hour casting time. However, because the invocation specifically mentions “a Magic action,” it raises the question: does this enable Find Familiar to be cast in a single action instead?
Understanding the Magic Action
The 2024 Player’s Handbook describes the Magic action as:

When you take the Magic action, you cast a spell that has a casting time of an action or use a feature or magic item that requires a Magic action to be activated.

It further clarifies:

If you cast a spell that has a casting time of 1 minute or longer, you must take the Magic action on each turn of that casting, and you must maintain Concentration while you do so. If your Concentration is broken, the spell fails, but you don’t expend a spell slot.

For spells with a casting time longer than one action (such as Find Familiar’s usual one-hour duration), this means the caster must take the Magic action on each turn until the spell is complete, maintaining concentration the entire time. Thus, 600 Magic actions would be needed to complete a one-hour cast.
However, Pact of the Chain specifies casting Find Familiar as “a Magic action,” with “a” implying a single action, rather than the extended casting time. Could this wording mean that Find Familiar can be cast with just one action through this invocation?
Comparing Other Abilities
For contrast, let’s examine other abilities that grant free spell casts without altering casting times, like the Magic Initiate feat:
“You can cast it once without a spell slot, and you regain the ability to cast it in that way when you finish a Long Rest.”
This feat lacks any mention of the Magic action, meaning it requires the spell’s standard casting time. Other feats and abilities, such as Fey-Touched, Shadow-Touched, the Ranger’s Hunter’s Mark, Paladin’s Smite, and Warlock’s Steps of the Fey, follow this same wording. This difference suggests that Pact of the Chain might uniquely allow Find Familiar to be cast within a single action.
In-Game Impact
If “a Magic action” allows Find Familiar to be cast in a single action, this provides a substantial tactical benefit: Warlocks could summon a familiar mid-combat if theirs is defeated, without waiting the usual one-hour casting time. However, if the invocation still requires the full hour, the Warlock would need to take 600 consecutive Magic actions, maintaining concentration throughout, which makes this ability much less viable in immediate situations.
When compared to the spell’s ritual casting option (which takes only an extra 10 minutes at 70 minutes total), the advantage of a free cast without expending a spell slot feels less impactful. Since the ritual option already allows Warlocks to avoid using a spell slot, the added flexibility of this invocation seems limited unless it truly shortens the casting time to a single action.
As always, interpretation ultimately rests with the Dungeon Master. However, the invocation’s specific wording of “a Magic action” strongly implies that Find Familiar could be cast in one action, making this invocation far more versatile and combat-friendly.
Does “a Magic action” imply a faster casting time, or should the invocation follow the usual one-hour casting?

Just realized this same question could apply to Druids with:
Level 2: Wild Companion
You can summon a nature spirit that assumes an animal form to aid you. As a Magic action, you can expend a spell slot or a use of Wild Shape to cast the Find Familiar spell without Material components.
When you cast the spell in this way, the familiar is Fey and disappears when you finish a Long Rest.

Fun fact: in 5e-2014, (ritual) spells could only be cast as rituals by characters who have a feature that lets them do so.  e.g. druids but not rangers.  And not warlocks unless they took pact of the tome and the Book of Ancient Secrets
invocation.  (Pacts used to be mutually exclusive with each other, but now they're both just eldritch invocations.  Book of Ancient Secrets is gone; you no longer get to add as many rituals as you want to your book, including higher level spells.)

@PeterCordes, the 2014 PoC let you cast Find Familiar as a ritual. "You learn the find familiar spell and can cast it as a ritual." Specific beats general.

Yes, Pact of the Chain allows Find Familiar to be cast as a Single Magic Action
As noted under Exceptions Supersede General Rules,

When an exception and a general rule disagree, the exception wins.

Pact of the Chain explicitly supersedes the normal 1 hour casting time for Find Familiar.

You learn the Find Familiar spell and can cast it as a Magic action without expending a spell slot.

Where "a Magic action" is a species of Action. Therefore, the Pact of the Chain enables a character can cast Find Familiar as a single Magic action without expending a spell slot.
Of note, casting Find Familiar still requires 10+ GP of incense, which serves as a resource limitation on this feature.

Components: V, S, M (burning incense worth 10+ GP, which the spell consumes)


Compare and Contrast:
Contrast this with the 2014 version:

You learn the find familiar spell and can cast it as a ritual.

We can infer from the very explicit change that this was designer intent. Since the empowered familiar is the central feature of the pact, the hour long casting time made re-summoning the familiar extremely costly in comparison to the benefits of the other Pact Boons.
Finally, for comparison, the casting time of Find Steed has also been reduced to an action. And, as you've noted, the same is true for a Wild Companion.

As it is currently written “You learn the Find Familiar spell and can cast it as a Magic action without expending a spell slot.”
But, why? Why was it necessary to state "a Magic action" unless the casting time needed to be clarified?
If it instead had been written as “You learn the Find Familiar spell and can cast it without expending a spell slot.” then we would know, by reading the casting time of the Find Familiar spell that it would be 1 hour or Ritual.
Or Ritual? Did the developers state that it is cast as "a Magic action" to stipulate that the Warlock could not cast the Find Familiar as a Ritual?
I don't believe so, as it already states it is cast without expending a spell slot, which is what casting a spell as a Ritual also achieves.
